# Using both OAuth and Basic Auth in Asp.Net Web Api with Owin

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

I've implemented OAuth authentication in my Web Api project based [on these blog posts](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)

It works well, including the refresh token logic.

I want to add an option for basic authentication as well for a couple of calls for scheduled jobs.

I've tried adding a Basic Auth solution as middleware but I'm still getting 401 asking for the Bearer token.

I can get it to work by removing the [Authorize] attribute from those api calls and checking manually in code if the user is authenticated but seems like the wrong way to solve it.

Is there a way to support both Basic Auth and OAuth authentication using OWin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about you attribute your actions or controller with you want to implement Basic authentication with the attribute `[OverrideAuthentication]` Then you create custom authentication filter attribute which inherits from `Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter` as the code below

```
public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var req = context.Request;
        // Get credential from the Authorization header 
        //(if present) and authenticate
        if (req.Headers.Authorization != null && "basic".Equals(req.Headers.Authorization.Scheme, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var rawCreds = req.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;

            var credArray = GetCredentials(rawCreds);

            var clientId = credArray[0];
            var secret = credArray[1];

            if (ValidCredentials(clientId, secret))
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim>()
                      {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, clientId)
                      };

                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Basic");
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new[] { identity });
                // The request message contains valid credential
                context.Principal = principal;
            }
            else
            {
                context.ErrorResult = new UnauthorizedResult(new AuthenticationHeaderValue[0], context.Request);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            context.ErrorResult = new UnauthorizedResult(new AuthenticationHeaderValue[0], context.Request);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private string[] GetCredentials(string rawCred)
    {

        var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");

        var cred = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(rawCred));

        var credArray = cred.Split(':');

        if (credArray.Length == 2)
        {
            return credArray;
        }
        else
        {
            return credArray = ":".Split(':');
        }

    }

    private bool ValidCredentials(string clientId, string secret)
    {

        //compare the values from web.config

        if (clientId == secret)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        context.Result = new ResultWithChallenge(context.Result);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public class ResultWithChallenge : IHttpActionResult
    {
        private readonly IHttpActionResult next;
        public ResultWithChallenge(IHttpActionResult next)
        {
            this.next = next;
        }
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync( CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var response = await next.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Add(new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic"));
            }
            return response;
        }
    }

    public bool AllowMultiple
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Now you use it to attribute you controllers or actions as the code below:

```
 [OverrideAuthentication]
    [BasicAuthentication]
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
}
```

Notice how we are creating claims identity and setting the Authentication scheme to Basic, you can put any claims you want here.

Comment: I've used filters for custom authentication in previous projects, I guess for a few calls in an API that mostly uses other auth schemes this makes more sense than an Owin middleware that executes on every call looking for a basic auth header